# GRPC TLS c++ communication returns ssl_transport_security.cc:1723] No match found for server name: 10.100.102.5

Tags: c++, debugging, openssl, grpc, tls1.2

I created a grpc *insecure* server correctly.
Now i am trying to make it secured.
my code is :

**server:**
std::string key = readFileContent("server.key");
std::string cert = readFileContent("server.crt");
std::string root = readFileContent("ca.crt");

grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions::PemKeyCertPair pkcp = {key, cert};
grpc::SslServerCredentialsOptions ssl_opts;
ssl_opts.pem_root_certs = root;
ssl_opts.pem_key_cert_pairs.push_back(pkcp);
ssl_opts.client_certificate_request = GRPC_SSL_REQUEST_AND_REQUIRE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE_AND_VERIFY;
std::shared_ptrgrpc::ServerCredentials creds = grpc::SslServerCredentials(ssl_opts);
builder.AddListeningPort("10.100.102.5:5055", cred);
builder.RegisterService(service);
std::unique_ptrgrpc::Server serverPtr = builder.BuildAndStart();
std::unique_ptr server(std::move(serverPtr));
server->Wait();

**client:**

std::string key = readFileContent("client.key");
std::string cert = readFileContent("client.crt");
std::string root = readFileContent("ca.crt");

grpc::SslCredentialsOptions ssl_opts {root, key, cert};
auto ssl_creds = grpc::SslCredentials(ssl_opts);
uto stub_ = RemoteSigner::NewStub("10.100.102.5:5055",ssl_creds);
ethereum::validator::accounts::v2::ListPublicKeysResponse reply;
ClientContext context;
stub_->ListValidatingPublicKeys(&context, ::google::protobuf::Empty(), &reply);

**generate my keys with :**

openssl genrsa -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj  "/C=SP/ST=Spain/L=Valdepenias/O=Test/OU=Test/CN=Root"

openssl genrsa -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out server.key 4096
openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj  "/C=SP/ST=Spain/L=Valdepenias/O=Test/OU=Server/CN=10.100.102.5"
openssl x509 -req -passin pass:1234 -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out server.crt

openssl rsa -passin pass:1234 -in server.key -out server.key

openssl genrsa -passout pass:1234 -des3 -out client.key 4096
openssl req -passin pass:1234 -new -key client.key -out client.csr -subj  "/C=SP/ST=Spain/L=Valdepenias/O=Test/OU=Client/CN=10.100.102.5"
openssl x509 -passin pass:1234 -req -days 365 -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client.crt

openssl rsa -passin pass:1234 -in client.key -out client.key

receive this error : transport_security.cc:1723] No match found for server name: 10.100.102.5.
can you help me find the problem please?

Comment: https://github.com/sandtable/ssl_grpc_example/issues/3

Comment: What does `openssl s_client -connect 10.100.102.5:5055 -showcerts` say? Is the correct certificate presented? Also, have you tried putting the [IP address into the SAN extension field](https://geekflare.com/san-ssl-certificate/)?

Comment: @TomoCeferin if my server and client are on the same ip this works.
But when my server is in different ip my client do (uto stub_ = RemoteSigner::NewStub("10.100.102.5:5055",ssl_creds);" and the answer will be 
transport_security.cc:1723] No match found for server name: 10.100.102.5